# Why can't activator resolve a custom dependency in local maven repository?

Tags: playframework, sbt, mailchimp, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application using Java.

I've forked the mail chimp java api wrapper repository, I've extended it and changed the module version with `2.0.1.2-beta`.

I've installed my module into the local maven repository. Then, I've tried to refer to it from my Play application's build, but the `update` command in play shell (`activator update`) give me the following errors:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta {compile=[default(compile)]}:
[warn]  URI has an authority component
[warn]  URI has an authority component
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta {compile=[default(compile)]}:
    URI has an authority component
    URI has an authority component
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)

...

[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta {compile=[default(compile)]}:
[error]     URI has an authority component
[error]     URI has an authority component
```

This is my rilevant's part of `build.sbt` file:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
    Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
    "Local Play Repository" at "file://$HOME/.ivy2/local",
    "Local Maven Repository" at "file://$HOME/.m2/repository"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.ecwid" % "ecwid-mailchimp" % "2.0.1.2-beta"
)
```

What's wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you face the error sbt tells you to run `last *:update` to see the full output:

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
```

While reproducing the case, I found `last *:update` quite useful as it showed me:

```
[debug] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/2.0.1.2-beta/ecwid-mailchimp-2.0.1.2-beta.pom
[debug]     sonatype-snapshots: no ivy file found for com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta
[debug]         tried file://$HOME/.ivy2/local/com/ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/2.0.1.2-beta/ecwid-mailchimp-2.0.1.2-beta.pom
[debug] problem occurred while resolving dependency: com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta {compile=[default(compile)]} with Local Play Repository: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
[debug]     at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
[debug]     at sbt.IO$.toFile(IO.scala:76)
[debug]     at sbt.ConvertResolver$LocalIfFileRepo.getResource(ConvertResolver.scala:222)
```

I don't think `$HOME` has been resolved and hence the issue.

Remove `"Local Play Repository" at "file://$HOME/.ivy2/local"` and start over. It's included by default and you don't need it in the build explicitly.

You should rather use `Path.userHome.absolutePath` not `$HOME` as described in [Resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Resolvers):

> sbt can search your local Maven repository if you add it as a
>   repository:
>
> ```
> resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
> ```
>
> or, for convenience:
>
> ```
> resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
> ```

With the following `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
    Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
    Resolver.mavenLocal
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.ecwid" % "ecwid-mailchimp" % "2.0.1.2-beta"
)
```

`update` gets stalled unable to resolve `com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta` that's another issue:

```
> update
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/uri-authority/}uri-authority...
[info] Resolving com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta ...
[warn]  module not found: com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/com.ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/2.0.1.2-beta/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/2.0.1.2-beta/ecwid-mailchimp-2.0.1.2-beta.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/2.0.1.2-beta/ecwid-mailchimp-2.0.1.2-beta.pom
[warn] ==== Maven2 Local: tried
[warn]   file:/Users/jacek/.m2/repository/com/ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/2.0.1.2-beta/ecwid-mailchimp-2.0.1.2-beta.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.ecwid:ecwid-mailchimp:2.0.1.2-beta (/Users/jacek/sandbox/uri-authority/build.sbt#L7-10)
[warn]        +- default:uri-authority_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.ecwid#ecwid-mailchimp;2.0.1.2-beta: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 30, 2014 11:39:21 PM
```